# SD card had bad sectors after chkdsk. Is that Logical or physical ?and path from here

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery, linux, partitions, app2sd

This is about `data corruption` on android . The primary issue relates to `bad blocks / clusters` and it happens to be android platform. So this is a `super user` and NOT `android` enthusiast question. answers to this question will apply to ANY corrupt card whether PC or android. So its thoughtless to tag this is android

This is a [Sandisk 128gb  ( leave this link  - its not an ad .Specific card indicates other paras like memory channels , write speed etc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010Q57S62) card I am using on an `Android Nougat` device.

This is the 2nd time the card had corruption issues. 1st one I bought got Write Locked . Present Replacement was provided
The card has a lot of `bad clusters`. 2 things got me to sniff this :

- `whatsApp` directory ( which had a bind to `whatsapp` dir on internal ) : the image directory can no longer be written to
- Phone randomly reboots and next time  `exFat` partition is not mounted ( I used `app2sd` and partitioned the card to `ext4` 10gb  to link my apps and rest if `exfat` )

ran a `chkdksk` on windows 7 and it would autoterminate on initial run & persisting on running gave me repeated message "# `cluster` moved for file " ( cant recollect exact verbiage ). It could Never complete it but aborted with the message . "corruption found in card "

questions :

- How do I know if there is logical  or physical bad cluster. Any tool / test ?

   Here's something I did - that made me think logical. I removed the images directory ( which was  write locked and so as long as the binding was on , whatsapp images could not be downloaded. Once I  switched off `folder mount` tool that enforced this, it would work ) after moving the contents to dir2 and renamed dir2 to original dir. after del the original dir. Now for sometime  whatsapp binding would work and the same problem came again . So I tend to think but need confirmation.
- I am thinking of salvaging the contents of `exfat` partition and then format partition and instead create 2 `ext4` partitions ( or `FF2S`. Tell me which is better) . One is for less write apps. My photos etc here and other smaller one just for whatsapp and then copy back contents to relevant partitions.

If I do this. There is no  out of box support for `ext4` partitions for android ( isn't ,pl confirm) ? how do I auto mount without 3rd party utils ( `fstab` ? ) 
How do I auto mount the extra `ext4 - fstab` ?
Will this help avoid the above problem ?

- While I still have the corrupt block partition  is *there ANY other tool* that will run  till the end and identify all bad blocks so they can be  kept aside .I tried `aparted` for `android` which runs `fsck ( exFat` sub ) and the report came normal in < 1 min .

Comment: Some errors are marginal, not hard or foreseeable, so you cannot assume anything. Our advice on SD card errors have always been the same : Get a new one, nobody can fix a bad card.

Comment: Are you sure the SDcard is genuine? I strongly recommend you to test it before using it. For example using the Windows tool [**H2Testw**](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml) it uses the full sdcard and checks it it really has the size it claims to have.

Comment: I am aware of fakes. Yep this is tested by H2testW - before I used it I ran the brute test

Comment: Sometimes the specific card ( usually depending on price ) will have extremely fine wiring, this is the case with many large storage device's on small physical devices like USB Memory Sticks & SD Cards... The card actually has an overheating protection to stop the wires from becoming damaged, This will stop Read & Write access to the device temporarily to allow cooling... This seems to cause a R/W Error for a computer... Instead of waiting for access, it immediately registers the current sector it was scanning as unusable... You need to follow the manufacturer instructions carefully... 5mb p/w

Comment: Have you tried BadBlocks on an Android... @Unknown:/ $ badblocks Usage: badblocks [-b block_size] [-i input_file] [-o output_file] [-svwnf] [-c blocks_at_once] [-d delay_factor_between_reads] [-e max_bad_blocks] [-p num_passes] [-t test_pattern [-t test_pattern [...]]] device [last_block [first_block]]....... OR FIX THE DRIVE WITH CHECK DISK ... `chkdsk -Drive -f` .... If a nondestructive -f won't fix it... try a destructive fix with -r (it implies -f ) `chkdsk -r`

Comment: As a Side comment to the "Nobody can fix a bad card" ... You can fix a bad storage device... Bad sectors & clusters have always been a part of digital storage, HDD's used to come with detailed formatting instructions to format around the bad sectors from building it... It is impossible not to get a bad sector every now and again... The fix & the reason we don't need to format around bad sectors anymore is because computers do it automatically, they have a reserved amount of usable sectors that are only ever used as replacements if and when a sector becomes unusable... ....

Comment: You hypothetically just need to force the device to use the reserved sectors.... However... If you run out of reserved sectors, you need to do an Old School low level format... Around the bad sectors per-say

Comment: Yes I ran chkdsk with /r /x  options & thats when it  puked with all these errors .  My questions are 1) How to successfully run some file system utiility that will make  bad sectors .chkdsk aborts 2) if I back up data and format all partitions will those bad sectors  be again available for use ( logical bad sector ) or they will cause the same issues again

Comment: #  system utility that will mark bad sectors